# Using get method on form, part of action url doesnt show up when submitted

Tags: php, forms

I have a strange issue where I have the following form/php form handler:

```
    <form id="search" method="get" action="page.php?pg=xxxxxx">
```

On submit, in the url I get domain.com/page.pgp?action=xxxx....(more get parameters here). How can I pass the pg=xxxx into the action url correctly? I tried throwing an & sign (page.php?pg=xxxxxx&) but that didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the pg value of "xxxxxx" incorrectly. These values should be passed in the input tags inside the form, for instance:

```
<form id="search" method="get" action="page.php>
  <input type="hidden" name="pg" value="xxxxxx">
  <input name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

the previous code creates a form with a button called "Submit", and when you press it, it takes you to your page action.php with the query string you wanted in the url:

> http://www.foo.com/action.php?pg=xxxxxx

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: How's your answer different from mine?

Comment: @j08691 I explained what he was doing correctly. Your answer is correct, though I thought I should give an explanation of what he was doing wrong. He has a fundamental misunderstanding of how forms pass the "get" information in the query string. Also he should be taking out the pg=xxxxxx from his previous code inside the form tag element.

Comment: @Webeng Thank you so much! That worked perfectly. And thank you for the explanation, I haven't used too many get forms yet. Appreciate it!

Comment: @Jazzerlol glad I could help! If this answer is the one that worked for you, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark on the left of the answer so that future users know that it is what worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden input to your form instead:

```
<input type="hidden" name="pg" value="xxxxxx" />
```